# Description in post merge notice should have a sentence cap like every other post notice description

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, merged-questions, post-notices

Currently, the descriptions under closed/locked/protected/bounty notices are in proper sentence case:

> ### closed as noise or pointless by [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)♦ just now
>
> This question does not add anything useful; having it present on the site is actively harmful because it distracts from other more useful questions.

> ### locked by [Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9)♦ 2 hours ago
>
> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info [visit meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

> ### protected by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community)♦ yesterday
>
> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) on this site.

> ### This question has an open [bounty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) worth +500 reputation from [Pekka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138112/pekka) ending in 7 days.
>
> This question has not received enough attention.

However, the merge notice starts in lowercase:

> ### merged by [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock)♦ 2 days ago
>
> this question was merged with **Some exactly-cloned question** because it is an exact duplicate of that question.

Is anyone up for correcting this inconsistency?

Comment: The open bounty notice heading is different, because it's a complete sentence... sufficiently different, IMO, to either warrant a different post or no action altogether.

Comment: I just posted a duplicate without realizing it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198800/

Comment: Come on, guys...I've bountied this and still no response?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix went out with build rev `2015.1.6.2914` on meta and rev `2015.1.6.2145` on sites. [Here's one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652927/?noredirect=1) with that notice for verification.

Comment: That's great, long time passed already :) So the bounty is yours once I see the shiny capitals :D

Comment: So, [tag:status-completed]? Or do you wait until  the build is deployed?

Comment: waiting for the build to go out

Comment: [YESSSSSSSSSSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079040/how-do-i-remove-documents-with-node-js-mongoose)